# Какой части речи слово?

Tags: причастия, наречия, части-речи

Первенство было завоёвано командой вполне **заслуженно**.

Подскажите, пожалуйста. С одной стороны, слово можно рассматривать как наречие: завоёвано (как? каким образом?) заслуженно, а с другой — как краткое причастие (от слова "заслужить").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все в частности да наоборот.

Слово **завоевано** — это краткое причастие, а **заслуженно** — наречие.

**завоевано** от слова *ЗАВОЕВАТЬ*.

Примеры предложений:

1. Я в этом не уверена, – ответила Ада с застенчивой наивностью, которая завоевала бы мое сердце, если б оно давно уже не было (каково?) **завоевано**, – но мне кажется, он ждет за дверью.
2. Мои футболисты проявили самоотверженность и отвагу и (как?) **заслуженно** победили.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @MuratSebert, пожалуйста. Рекомендую ставить оценку ответам, если они действительно вам помогли.